# Issue with SwiftUI TextFields in Xcode 14.3.1 - Compatibility between Old and New Projects

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm currently working with SwiftUI in Xcode 14.3.1, and I've encountered an issue related to TextFields when transitioning between an old project and a new project. Here's a breakdown of my observations:

**Observation in New Project:**

TextFields are functioning as expected in SwiftUI Preview.
I developed a module as a standalone demo project, which worked fine.
The new project has a minimum supported iOS version of 16.

**Observation in Old Project:**

I incorporated the component from the new project into the old project.
The component rendered correctly within the old project.
However, the TextFields within the component are not functioning as expected.
The old project also has a minimum supported iOS version of 16.
What's particularly surprising is that after rendering the component in the old project, the TextFields also cease to work correctly in the new project.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to address this issue and ensure consistent TextField functionality between the old and new projects.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.